# Precedence of initialized port/signal assigned to port in VHDL

Tags: initialization, vhdl

I have a question regarding initialization in VHDL. If I have an entity output port that is initialized to a certain value, but is assigned to a signal that is initialized to a different value, what initial value will the output assume. I mean a situation like the following:

```
entity TEST_ENTITY is
    Port (port0    : out    STD_LOGIC    := '0');
end TEST_ENTITY;

architecture Behavioral of TEST_ENTITY is
    signal signal0    : STD_LOGIC    := '1';

begin

    port0    <= signal0;
end Behavioral;
```

I would assume that the initialization value of the signal will take precedence. Is this correct?

Comment: You can demonstrate what happens yourself. Add  a context clause to the code (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`), and a [testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4D44.jpg) to monitor `port0`. Every process executes at least once during simulation model initialization, you'd capture the default value during initialization and any assigned value in a delta cycle without the advancement of simulation time. Sequential events on `port0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no precedence here. Signal assignments take at least one delta cycle to pass. So at time 0, `port0` will be `'0'` and `signal0` will be `'1'`. `Port0` will become `'1'` after 1 delta cycle has elapsed.